# typeid doesn't work with non-static member function

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, typeid

`clang` doesn't compile the third call to `typeid` below (see [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e61efc069f27dc35)). But I can't see anything in §5.2.8 that disallows this, specially when we consider that the expression `B::f` is not a glvalue of polymorphic class type (see paragraph 3). Also, according to this paragraph the expression `B::f` is an unevaluated operand, and as such, the call `typeid(B::f)` should compile. Note that `GCC` doesn't compile any of the calls to `typeid` below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct A{ int i; };
struct B{ int i; void f(); };

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(A::i).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(B::i).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(B::f).name() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @Yakk I tested with g++ and confirmed that none of the three compile, then edited the question to fix the double negation.

Comment: Putting `&` in from of them causes all this to work on both compilers, e.g. `&B::i`. But, I guess that's not the point! Why don't they work without `&`?

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the correction. As you can see I don't have the full command of the English language.

Comment: I've renamed the question title. Feel free to change it again! The original question title was absolutely useless frankly :-)

Comment: Filed a bug report for this.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid `&A::f` is the syntax for forming pointer-to-member.  `A::f` isn't. I think `A::f` is invalid in most/all contexts except for having `&` behind.

Comment: It would appear that MSVC 2015 has the same behaviour as Clang, putting it ahead of GCC in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can tell `clang` is correct, using a non static member is only valid in an unevaluated context if it is a data member. So it looks like `gcc` is incorrect for the first two cases, but `gcc` works correctly in the case of `sizeof` and `decltype` which also have unevaluated operands.

From the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `5.1.1` *[expr.prim.general]*:

> An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static
>   member function of a class can only be used:

and includes the following bullet:

> if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears
>   in an unevaluated operand. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> struct S {
>     int m;
> };
> int i = sizeof(S::m); // OK
> int j = sizeof(S::m + 42); // OK
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

The rest of the bullets do not apply, they are as follows:

> - as part of a class member access (5.2.5) in which the object expression refers to the member’s class<sup>61</sup> or a class derived from that
>     class, or
> - to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), or
> - in a mem-initializer for a constructor for that class or for a class derived from that class (12.6.2), or
> - in a brace-or-equal-initializer for a non-static data member of that class or of a class derived from that class (12.6.2), or

We know that operand is unevaluated from section `5.2.8` which says:

> When typeid is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a
>   polymorphic class type, [...] The expression is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5).

We can see from the grammar that an *id-expression* is either an *unqualified-id* or a *qualified-id*:

```
id-expression:
    unqualified-id
    qualified-id
```

**Update**

Filed a gcc [bug report: typeid does not allow an id-expression that denotes a non-static data member](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68604).

Comment: Darn--had an almost identical answer nearly finished, but was working on formatting the syntax for `primary-expression` from 5.1.1 when you posted...

Answer (score 2):

`typeid(A::i).name()` doesn't quite do what I thought it would do. I expected it to be a pointer-to-member, but it's actually just an `int`.

To see this, run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A{ int i; };
struct B{ int i; void f(void); };

template<typename T>
void what_is_my_type() {
    std:: cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std:: endl;
}

int main()
{
    what_is_my_type<decltype(&A::i)>(); // "void what_is_my_type() [T = int A::*]"
    what_is_my_type<decltype(&B::i)>(); // "void what_is_my_type() [T = int B::*]"
    what_is_my_type<decltype(&B::f)>(); // "void what_is_my_type() [T = void (B::*)()]"

    what_is_my_type<decltype(A::i)>();  // "void what_is_my_type() [T = int]"
    what_is_my_type<decltype(B::i)>();  // "void what_is_my_type() [T = int]"
    // what_is_my_type<decltype(B::f)>();       //    doesn't compile

}
```

I've put the output in a comment after each call.

The first three calls work as expected - all three work and the type information includes the type of the struct (`A` or `B`) as well as the type of member.

The last three are different though. The final one doesn't even compile, and the first two simply print `int`. I think this is a clue as to what is wrong. It is possible, given a particular `A` or `B`, to take the address of that particular member:

```
A a;
int * x = &(a.i);
*x = 32;
```

but it is *not* possible (or even meaningful?) to do this:

```
B b;
???   y = &(a.f); // what does this even mean?
```

Finally, to emphasize that this is not about pointers, consider this:

```
A a;
B b;
int x = a.i;
int y = b.i;
??? z = b.f;  // what would this mean? What's its type?
```