# Which paragraph in the C++ Standard validates the expression `sizeof(S::m + 42)`used in the example below?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, sizeof

This is the example in [[expr.prim.id]/2 (2.3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#2.3):

```
struct S {
    int m;
};
int i = sizeof(S::m); // OK
int j = sizeof(S::m + 42); // OK
```

I'd like to know which paragraph in the Standard (N4713) validates the expression `sizeof(S::m + 42)` used above.

Comment: [Maybe related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28054077/1708801)

Comment: Why should there be a specific paragraph? The C++ Standard is a kind of holistic document.

Comment: N4659 is the standard; N4713 is a C++20 draft

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are asking. The very paragraph you are quoting says why it's OK. Do you have some reason to believe there is another problem with the code? If so then discuss this in your question.

Comment: @M.M `S::m + 42` is not an _id-expression_

Comment: @Alexander the operand of `sizeof` can be any expression, there's no restriction to id-expression.  `S::m` is an id-expression,  `S::m + 42` isn't , but that's fine

Comment: @M.M The operand of sizeof is discussed in [expr.sizeof]. But I can't find any paragraph in this clause that could validate the alluded construction.

Comment: @Alexander The operand of `sizeof` can be any expression. `S::m + 42` is an expression. If you don't consider that "validated" then you will need to explain further.

Comment: It would really help this question if you could articulate why it is you believe it should *not* be okay.

Comment: @Barry I was under the (wrong) impression that the operand of a sizeof could be any expression **not** surrounded by parentheses. But after reading more carefully [expr.sizeof]/1 I can see now that this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @M.M points out, the operand of `sizeof` can be any expression (8.5.2.3.1):

> [...] The operand is either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand, or a parenthesized type-id.

There are a few other restrictions noted in 8.5.2.3, but none apply here.

Note that it mentions that it can be an *unevaluated operand* -- this makes possible to use the non-static class member `S::m` here, see (8.2.3.1):

> An unevaluated operand is not evaluated. [ Note: In an unevaluated operand, a non-static class member may be named ([expr.prim]) and naming of objects or functions does not, by itself, require that a definition be provided ([basic.def.odr]). An unevaluated operand is considered a full-expression. — end note ]

Which mentions the paragraph that you were referring to in the question (8.4.4.2.3):

> An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used: [...] if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.